# Is it possible to call functions from other servers?

Tags: php

Sorry for my bad English

Is it possible if I ***read text as code*** for a function on one server and execute it on another server?

For example, i have a code in my server1 index.php with domain1.com

```
<?php
    function outputString()
    {
        echo "Test";
    }
?>
```

And I want to call the function above on server2 for example index.php with domain2.com

I have tried using the code below but there is an error

```
<?php
    require_once('http://domain1.com/index.php');

    outputString()
?>
```

the error that appears

```
[25-Jan-2019 16:30:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function outputstring() in /home/website/domain2.com/index.php on line 3
```

So, can I call functions from other servers using other methods? Or is this impossible? Thank you

Comment: not like this, *in theory* - you could download a webpage, and with file_put_contents recreate the functions on your server - but I guess.. what's the point. If you know the function, you might as well just recreate in a .php file without the overheads

Comment: In the error output, it states `undefined function outputstring()` but your code says `outputString()` is there possibly a typo in the code?

Comment: you could make an api and use something like if ($_GET['outputstring'] == "true") { echo "Test"; } and you should use something like file_get_contents instead of require_once()

Comment: @EPKgames not a bad shout - an API probs is the best way to go - though if the OP has control over both domains (as it seems), probs best to just have the function in both projects - though.. if domain1 is wanting public accessibility outside of OPs projects, then API is a good way to go

Comment: @treyBake tnx, also it is indeed better to make the functions on the other domain because the page waiting time will be very long because it needs to wait for the other webserver to respond.

Comment: @KRichardson it's not a typo, but it's like that written in error_log

Comment: @EPKgames Thank you for your advice, I will try it

Comment: The duplicate isn't correct. That's about interacting between 2 servers. Not simply running a function from one on another.

Comment: Store the code on server1 in a string *without <?php tags*. On server 2 use `file_get_contents` to store the string and then `eval($string)`;

Comment: [`eval` is evil!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/)

Comment: CURL will do !!!! check the examples on http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php